# create-react-app is deployed on Heroku but page is blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy a `react` app on `heroku` but after deploying it on heroku its showing blank page,I've also created this app using `buildpack mars/create-react-app`

This is what I'm getting on deployed project:

[image: This is what I'm getting on deployed project]

Here's my `package.json` file:

```js
    {
      "name": "covid-19",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "homepage": "covid-19-stats-by-anny-v3",
      "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "fetch": "^1.1.0",
        "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
        "material-table": "^1.65.0",
        "mui-datatables": "^3.3.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-social-icons": "^4.1.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to add what you've configured on the server-side (expressjs)?

Comment: I was facing same issue. Create react app production build not loading chunk .js file.  I created express server and served it as static file it worked. worth trying.

Comment: i didnt included expressjs in it @MwamiTovi

Comment: @HarishMahamure how you did that,can you send me some tutorial about same?

Comment: I did exactly what @HarishMahamure mentioned above. `Heroku` considers react projects to be configured for `nodejs` setup. And I actually see you have `expressjs` in your `package.json`...

Comment: I have answered you. Please follow steps. they will help you

Comment: [Here are a couple of steps](https://gist.github.com/Mwamitovi/c83379367d3221fd782138ebc1adfe96) to give you an idea of what's you can update.

Comment: @mwamiTovi we can do it directly. Please check my answer

Comment: Yes, i've seen your answer @HarishMahamure. I was hoping that our colleague, here, tries out the answer in the that link (it's a gist at GitHub). Once he confirms that it works or doesn't work, it's easier to update there than here...before I post the final answer. Makes sense?

Comment: I think the problem here is with your server.js file. Especially in the part where you define static folder path.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this white screen is JavaScript files are loaded into the browser.

There is the publicPath setting in your Webpack configuration to tell an app what its root path is. In our example, that would be https://www.yourwebsite.com/

If set correctly, it will base links like above from that URL – and your application will load like expected.

**Put this information is package.json file add these lines after version in package.json**

```
"homepage":"your app link"
```

and build the application again it will work.